# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sendall' PYTHON

Tags: python, python-2.7, ftp

My current python script:

```
import os
import ftplib
import hashlib
import glob


hashing = "123"
m = hashlib.md5()
m.update(hashing)
dd = m.hexdigest()

ftp = ftplib.FTP('localhost','kevin403','S$ip1234')
ftp.cwd('/var/www/html/image')

for image in glob.glob(os.path.join('Desktop/images/test*.png')):
  with open(image, 'rb') as file:
    ftp.storbinary('STOR '+dd+ '.png', file)

ftp.close()
ftp.quit()
```

Anybody know this error? I trying to send file over to another folder via ftp.

The error i got when running the script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/kevin403/wwq.py", line 21, in <module>
  ftp.quit()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 591, in quit
  resp = self.voidcmd('QUIT')
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 253, in voidcmd
  self.putcmd(cmd)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 181, in putcmd
  self.putline(line)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 176, in putline
  self.sock.sendall(line)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sendall'
```

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace?

Comment: @Raskayu i just added

Comment: Answer aded, check it out

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **FTP.quit()**
>   Send a QUIT command to the server and close the connection. This is the “polite” way to close a connection, but it may raise an exception if the server responds with an error to the QUIT command. This implies a call to the close() method which renders the FTP instance useless for subsequent calls (see below).
>
> **FTP.close()**
>   Close the connection unilaterally. This should not be applied to an already closed connection such as after a successful call to quit(). After this call the FTP instance should not be used any more (after a call to close() or quit() you cannot reopen the connection by issuing another login() method).

Just erase `ftp.close()`, since `ftp.quit()`  implies call `.close()` function you're telling to close two times, and then quit falls because socket was already closed.

[FTPlib Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html)